# Laplace Transform of a Multidimensional Partial Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, integral-transforms

I'm trying to use *Mathematica* to solve a multidimensional partial differential equation using Laplace tranforms. The PDE is as follows:

$$
\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial t}} = \frac{{{\partial ^2}T}}{{\partial {x^2}}}
$$

Where:

$$T(0,t)=T(1,t)=0$$
$$T(x,0)=\sin(\pi x)$$

Here is my progress so far:

```
In[172] := D[T[x, t], t] - D[T[x, t], {x, 2}]
Out[172] = Derivative[0, 1][T][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][T][x, t]

In[169] := LaplaceTransform[D[T[x, t], t] - D[T[x, t], {x, 2}], {t, x}, {t ,s}]
Out[169] = LaplaceTransform[Derivative[0, 1][T][x, t], {t, x}, {t, s}] - LaplaceTransform[Derivative[2, 0][T][x, t], {t, x}, {t, s}]

In[170] := ClearAll[x, t, eqn]
           eqn = D[T[x, t], t] - D[T[x, t], {x, 2}]
Out[171] = Derivative[0, 1][T][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][T][x, t]
```

But I'm really not sure if I'm on the right track. I'm not terribly concerned with solving the problem completely, but rather I'm held up on the syntax of converting the partial differential equation to "*Mathematica* form", and how to proceed with *Mathematica*.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you taking the Laplace transform only in the variable `t`? If so, do `LaplaceTransform[expr, t, s]` instead, where `expr` is your expression involving the derivatives.

Comment: I suppose maybe I'm confused about that.. I thought I would take it in the variable t, treating x as an additional parameter so that I would have T(x,s) instead of T(x,t). Can you confirm that In[172] and In[169] from my code block are correct, by chance? Or... Out[171].. I think that seemed to be my most correct...

Comment: 171 and 172 are the same. They look correct. The Laplace transform is basically not evaluating because the syntax is wrong, I think. Hold on.

Answer (score 3):

First, define the equation and take `LaplaceTransform`, implementing the initial condition along the way:

```
eqn = D[T[x, t], t] - D[T[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0
LaplaceTransform[eqn, t, s] /. T[x, 0] -> Sin[π x]
```

[image]

In the second term, we actually can interchange the order of integration and differentiation to see that it's just `D[LaplaceTransform[T[x, t], t, s], {x, 2}]`. Therefore, we replace the transformed function with a dummy:

```
eqn2 = s tT[x, s] - D[tT[x, s], {x, 2}] - Sin[π x] == 0;
```

We can then solve this analytically:

```
func = tT[x, s] /. First@DSolve[{eqn2, tT[0, s] == 0, tT[1, s] == 0}, tT[x, s], x]
(* Sin[π x]/(π^2 + s) *)
```

Finally, then

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[func, s, t]
(* E^(-π^2 t) Sin[π x] *)
```